# Cannot delete a queue via the artemis web console

Tags: activemq-artemis

I'm experimenting with artemis 2.13.0 on Docker.
I can create a queue programmatically but I cannot delete it via the web console.

Sometimes destroyQueue appears as an option in the operations for the queue. Other times it does not.
Recently I cannot destroy the queue from the console.

I get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException : No operation destroyQueue found on MBean org.apache.activemq.artemis:address="example",broker="77643207e938",component=addresses,queue="example",routing-type="anycast",subcomponent=queues
```

Any ideas why this might be happening?

Thanks

Comment: It's hard to say what's happening without a more thorough description of the use-case. Please include your client code, screenshots of the console if possible, and your `broker.xml`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `destroyQueue` is an operation only accessible the trought [ActiveMQServerControl](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/management.html#server-management), ie to destroy the queue with the name `TEST` using the MBean `org.apache.activemq.artemis:broker`:

```
curl -H "Origin:http://localhost" -u admin:admin http://localhost:8161/console/jolokia/exec/org.apache.activemq.artemis:broker=%220.0.0.0%22/destroyQueue%28java.lang.String%29/TEST
```

You are getting this error because the MBean used in your request is `org.apache.activemq.artemis:address` while should be `org.apache.activemq.artemis:broker` as in the previous example.

This could be caused by the selection of the wrong node in the left panel.
To solve this issue, select the broker node in the left panel before to execute the `destroyQueue` operation.

Comment: Perfect. This works. It seems when selected on the main queue panel/page it must default to address rather than queue.